# Images rotate automatically

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, image-processing

I have a iPhone app that uploads pictures to my server. One major issue I am having is a rotating one.

For some reason if I upload a picture from my iPhone, some pictures will automatically rotate. The one's that do get rotated are the ones in portrait mode. I have no code in my script that rotates the images.

How does a server exactly process tall images? Should I modify my php file to check to rotate it ahead after it automatically rotates? Should I code something in my iPhone app that will check this?

Any help is appreciated!

*PS: If you need code, feel free to ask!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some pictures(jpg) have exif data that tells the position the camera was when the picture was shot.

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php#76964

You may rotate the pictures server-side like this

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am having to rebuild my Apache with EXIF allowed. I will get back to you if it works.

Comment: Just installed it and after printing the array from an image, ORIENTATION isn't in the exif array. Any ideas?

Comment: what does the exif tag contains? You may see the exif tags with lots of different programs not just by using php

Answer (score 0):

Or a better way is to use this library

https://github.com/Intervention/image

And simply use like this-

```
$img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->orientate();
```

More can be found **[here](http://image.intervention.io/api/orientate)**.

Answer (score 0):

When you take a picture your phone saves any rotation metadata in EXIF headers. When you upload the image to your server, that metadata is still sitting there but it's your job to apply it to the image to rotate it (if you want). In PHP you can use a function called [exif_read_data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php):

```php
function correctImageOrientation($filename)
{
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    if ($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
        $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
        if ($orientation != 1) {
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            $deg = 0;
            switch ($orientation) {
                case 3:
                    $deg = 180;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $deg = 270;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    $deg = 90;
                    break;
            }
            if ($deg) {
                $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);
            }
            imagejpeg($img, $filename, 95);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it simply call the function after you save the file. For more info and an additional PHP solution see [the original source](https://medium.com/thetiltblog/fixing-rotated-mobile-image-uploads-in-php-803bb96a852c).